# Toggling internet sharing when ethernet cable dis/connected

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, airport, internet-sharing

The room where I'm staying has an ethernet connection, so when I'm there I turn on internet sharing so that my Kindle and phone will have a WiFi connection. But when I'm at work I have to use Airport to connect to the internet. This means that whenever I arrive at home or at work I have to open the internet sharing pane in order to switch sharing on or off.

So I was wondering whether there's some way to automate this, i.e. have internet sharing activate automatically whenever there's an ethernet connection available, and switch off whenever there isn't.

After a bit of web searching it seemed that the app [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) ought to be able to do it, but I haven't been able to get that to work and that app seems quite a lot more complex than what I'm looking for, so I'm hoping someone can lead me to a simpler solution.

**Update** I'm now running 10.8, which switches automatically by default, so this is not longer an issue for me. (Internet sharing is really buggy on 10.8 though, and I've basically stopped using it because it sometimes gets so confused that WiFi networking stops altogether until I reboot - but that's a separate issue.) I'll leave this question here just in case someone has a solution that might help others with the same issue.

Comment: Which version of MAC your using? I am using MAC OSX 10.7.5. I share internet on ethernet connection and if i disconnect the ethernet cable WiFi start working normal. As soon as I connect the cable back, mac will start internet sharing on.

Comment: @ShineethHamza see the tags - I'm using a MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard (10.6.8). If I disconnect the ethernet cable I have to go into System Preferences and manually switch off internet sharing, otherwise it can't access other WiFi networks.

Comment: I think you should check for custom workflows for Alfred App which can do this for you in a tap of keys

Comment: MAC is a makeup company...